# How do I set multiple unique indexes in schema in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that keeps getting duplicate documents because I have multiple servers writing to the database and sometimes two servers will insert the same document because they update at (almost) the same time.  The problem is, there are different ways that documents can be considered unique, and not all fields are required all the time.  Here are some examples.

This is my schema:

```
const Collection = new Schema(
    {
        accountID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Account", required: true},
        startDate: Date,
        threadID: String,
        confirmationCode: String,
        externalID: String,
    },
    {timestamps: true}
);
```

A document is unique if:

1. `accountID`,`startDate`, and `threadID` are all the same as another document
2. `accountID`, and `confirmationCode` are both the same as another document
3. `accountID`, and `externalID` are both the same as another document

Here are some indexes but I'm not sure they will work.

```
Reservation.index(
    {
        accountID: 1,
        startDate: 1,
        threadID: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_index_1", unique: true, sparse: true}
);

Reservation.index(
    {
        accountID: 1,
        confirmationCode: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_index_2", unique: true, sparse: true}
);

Reservation.index(
    {
        accountID: 1,
        externalID: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_index_3", unique: true, sparse: true}
);
```

Here are some example of documents and some duplicates:

```
// Unique
{
    _id: "id_1",
    accountID: "account1", 
    startDate: "2021-04-01",
    threadID: "threadID_1",
    confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_1" 
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    _id: "id_2",
    accountID: "account1", 
    startDate: "2021-04-02",
    threadID: "threadID_1",
    confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_2" 
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    _id: "id_3",
    accountID: "account1",
    startDate: "2021-04-03", 
    threadID: "threadID_1",
    // confirmationCode (not set)
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    _id: "id_4",
    accountID: "account1",
    // startDate (not set)
    // threadID (not set)
    confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_3" 
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    _id: "id_5",
    accountID: "account2",
    startDate: "2021-04-01", 
    // threadID: (not set),
    // confirmationCode (not set)
    externalID: "externalID_1"
}
// Duplicates of the docs above
{
    accountID: "account1",
    // startDate (not set)
    // threadID (not set)
    confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_1" // <-- is same as doc id_1 (violates Unique_index_2)
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    accountID: "account1",
    startDate: "2021-04-01",  // <-- is same as doc id_1 (violates Unique_index_1)
    threadID: "threadID_1", // <-- is same as doc id_1 (violates Unique_index_1)
    // confirmationCode (not set)
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    accountID: "account1",
    startDate: "2021-04-02",  // <-- is same as doc id_2 (violates Unique_index_1)
    threadID: "threadID_1", // <-- is same as doc id_2 (violates Unique_index_1)
    // confirmationCode (not set)
    // externalID (not set)
}
{
    accountID: "account2",
    // startDate (not set)
    // threadID (not set)
    // confirmationCode (not set)
    externalID: "externalID_1" // <-- is same as doc id_5 (violates Unique_index_3)
}
```

Uniqueness should be checked in this order:

1. If `accountID` and `confirmationCode` exists and are unique go to #2
2. If `accountID` and `externalID` exists and are unique go to #3
3. If `accountID`, `startDate` and `threadID` exists and are unique insert new document.

If it finds a match to any of the above, it should not insert a doc but rather update.  I think my use of `sparse` is correct but I want to make sure.

Will my unique index work for what I want?

Comment: Are there any particular duplicates from the list that don't work as expected? I copy-pasted your indexes and documents and got  `E11000 duplicate key error collection: so.Reservation index: Unique_index_2 dup key: { accountID: "account1", confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_1" }` after first duplicate.  As a side note, uniqueness has no order. It's a binary state. A document either satisfy all unique constraints or is rejected by any constrain violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These will probably not have the effect you want.  The sparse index will have an entry if the document has a value for *any* of the indexed fields, and the missing fields will be indexed as `null`

Consider what the index values will look like for each of the documents, and note that all of the `account1` documents have exactly the same key for `Unique_index_3`:

| Document | Unique_index_1 | Unique_index_2 | Unique_index_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <sub>{ _id: "id_1", accountID: "account1", startDate: "2021-04-01", threadID: "threadID_1", confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_1" // externalID (not set) }</sub> | <sub>account1:2021-04-01:threadID_1</sub> | <sub>account1:confirmationCode_1</sub> | <sub>account1:null</sub> |
| <sub>{ _id: "id_2", accountID: "account1", startDate: "2021-04-02", threadID: "threadID_1", confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_2" // externalID (not set) }</sub> | <sub>account1:2021-04-02:threadID_1</sub> | <sub>account1:confirmationCode_2</sub> | <sub>account1:null</sub> |
| <sub>{ _id: "id_3", accountID: "account1", startDate: "2021-04-03", threadID: "threadID_1", // confirmationCode (not set) // externalID (not set) }</sub> | <sub>account1:2021-04-03:threadID_1</sub> | <sub>account1:null</sub> | <sub>account1:null</sub> |
| <sub>{ _id: "id_4", accountID: "account1", // startDate (not set) // threadID (not set) confirmationCode: "confirmationCode_3" // externalID (not set) }</sub> | <sub>account1:null:null</sub> | <sub>account1:confirmationCode_3</sub> | <sub>account1:null</sub> |
| <sub>{ _id: "id_5", accountID: "account2", startDate: "2021-04-01", // threadID: (not set), // confirmationCode (not set) externalID: "externalID_1" }</sub> | <sub>account2:2021-02-01:null</sub> | <sub>account2:null</sub> | <sub>account2:externalID_1</sub> |

<sub>(Yes, I realize MongoDB doesn't use a colon as a separator for index values, but it is conveniently printable)</sub>

[Partial indexex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-indexes) would be useful.  Providing a partial filter expression that tests existence of a subset of the fields will prevent including the documents with missing fields in the index.

```
Reservation.index(
    {
        accountID: 1,
        startDate: 1,
        threadID: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_index_1", unique: true, 
      partialFilterExpression:{startDate: {$exists:true}, threadID:{$exists:true}}}
);

Reservation.index(
    {
        accountID: 1,
        confirmationCode: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_index_2", unique: true, 
      partialFilterExpression:{confirmationCode: {$exists:true}}
);

Reservation.index(
    {
        accountID: 1,
        externalID: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_index_3", unique: true, 
      partialFilterExpression:{externalID:{$exists:true}}
);
```

Note that this will not attempt to ensure uniqueness among the documents not matched by the partial filter.  For example, the docuemnt `{accountID:"account1"}` could be inserted many times.

Comment: Thank you!! I awarded you the bounty.